# Finding an object in javascript array

Tags: javascript

So this question has been asked before, but my case is a little bit a diffrent, as I have tried all the sollution suggested in this web site, I have an multidementional array :

```json
var array = [
{
    "dup":{ "lat":36.69507771893455,"lng":2.828052824475776 },
    "original":{ "lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}
},
{
    "dup":{ "lat":36.69507687630523,"lng":2.8280525056927672},
    "original":{ "lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}
},
{
    "dup":{ "lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280523980529324},
    "original":{ "lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}
},
{
    "dup":{ "lat":36.69507512369477,"lng":2.8280525056927672},
    "original":{ "lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}
},
{
    "dup":{ "lat":36.69507428106545,"lng":2.828052824475776},
    "original":{ "lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}
},
{
    "dup":{ "lat":36.695073504493834,"lng":2.828053342151293},
    "original":{ "lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}
},
...
]
```

and I have another small array :

```
var datax = {"lat":36.69507428106545,"lng":2.828052824475776}
```

All I wanted is to find the "original" that is in the same row with this "dup".
so far I tried find, filter, and grep, but none of this has solved my problem.

code that I have tried :

```js
var Cent = $.grep(array, function(e){ return e.dup== JSON.stringify(datax); });
contentString += " and "+Cent +"is the closer";
```

Comment: Do you want to return a new array or the index of the item?

Comment: You mean the same with `datax`?

Comment: a) show us what you tried, _always_. b) are you aware how object comparison works in JS (or maybe rather how it doesn’t, depending on initial assumptions)?

Comment: datax is "dup" and wanted to find the "original" that are in same row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still achieve this using `Array.filter()`:

```js
var array = [{"dup":{"lat":36.69507771893455,"lng":2.828052824475776},"original":{"lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}},{"dup":{"lat":36.69507687630523,"lng":2.8280525056927672},"original":{"lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}},{"dup":{"lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280523980529324},"original":{"lat":36.69507428106545,"lng":2.828052824475776}},{"dup":{"lat":36.69507512369477,"lng":2.8280525056927672},"original":{"lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}},{"dup":{"lat":36.69507428106545,"lng":2.828052824475776},"original":{"lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}},{"dup":{"lat":36.695073504493834,"lng":2.828053342151293},"original":{"lat":36.695076,"lng":2.8280580000000555}}];
var datax = {"lat":36.69507428106545,"lng":2.828052824475776}

var res = array.filter(item => item.original.lat === datax.lat && item.original.lng === datax.lng);
console.log(res);
```